# Laravel / Vue : unable to load vue component in blade tmeplate

Tags: laravel, vue.js, webpack

I am new to Laravel and Vue and trying to include a component in my blade template as below

Below is my **app.js**

```
require('./bootstrap');
window.Vue= require('vue');
Vue.component('Home',require('./components/home.vue').default);
```

**webpack.min.js**

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .sourceMaps();
```

Home.vue inside `resources/js/components/home.vue`

```
<template>
    <div class="home">Hello from home</div>
</template>
```

in my blade template, I have loaded app.js and added component as below

```
 <body class="antialiased">
        <Home></Home>
 </body>
```

now when I try to compile `npm run dev`  or `npm watch` it gives me the following error

> ERROR in ./resources/js/components/home.vue 1:0 Module parse failed:
> Unexpected token (1:0) You may need an appropriate loader to handle
> this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this
> file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
>
> > |     Hello from home |
>
> webpack compiled with 1 error

can someone please help me to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you shown the complete home.vue file, the script part with the export is missing:

```
<template>
    <div class="home">Hello from home</div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "Home"
    }
</script>
```

Or it may be also related to this line:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
```

You should try with:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').vue()
```

Answer (score 0):

While working with Vue, make sure that following dependencies have been properly installed:

1. VueJS (of course)
2. vue-loader (npm i vue-loader)
3. vue-template-compiler (npm i vue-template-compiler)

You can check those dependencies in your package.json file. If they are not there, then your SFC not going to work.

Export default is not a problem. There are compnents with just template and that's completely fine.